# Deserialization и Serialization readonly полей (Xml, Json)

Tags: c#, json, xml

Как можно записать данные в `readonly` поле модели? Не используя `IXmlSerializable`.
Хочу запретить редактирование модели.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "...")]
public sealed class AdditionalInformationKontur
{
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "...")]
        public readonly string ID;
}
```

Comment: сделайте poco классы конкретно для сериализации и мапьте их на модели. Так и модели останутся с ридонли полями и аттрибуты для сериализации на них вешать не придется